# ftrows_FTP...ndf file preventing a restore

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to restore a db with a backup, but it fails each time because of a file in use. The file is ftrow_FTC{xxxxxxx}.ndf

Does anyone know what this file is and what its for? Do I need it? If not, how can I get rid of it?  Thank you.

I should add, this is SQL 2012 server on a Server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the `ftrow_FTC{xxxxxxx}.ndf` if a [Full-Text Catalog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/create-and-manage-full-text-indexes) file. You're probably using SQL Server Management Studio wizard to restore that database. However, you can also use a t-sql command to do the restore.

In the latter case you could tell SQL Server to restore your full text catalog file under different name/path with the [RESTORE ... WITH MOVE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-transact-sql) command:

```
RESTORE DATABASE DBNAME from disk = N'd:\path\to\your\backup.bak' 
WITH MOVE 'ftrow_FTC{xxxxxxx}.ndf' TO 'd:\path\to\new\FT_location\ftrow_FTC{xxxxxxx}.ndf'
```

replace the `DBNAME` with your real DB name and the `ftrow` file name with real file name.

**UPDATE:** you can also easily restore your DB with full text catalog under different file name using SQL Server Management Studio dialog. During restore simply locate your ftrow file record in the DB files list and assign it to different path. That way you will not get conflict with the ftrow file used by your live DB.

HTH

Comment: This would be helpful, if I get into the bind and I have to restore the test db, then I can redirect the file. I would like to get rid of it though.

Comment: @RanG you will be able to drop that full text catalog after you fully restore the DB with the ftrow file relocated. After you drop it, it will not be included in future backups.

Comment: This is great, I'll test it out. How do I drop the ftrow file both on the Live and Test db?  Thank you so much

Comment: @RanG Expand your DB node in SSMS and Choose Storage->Full Text Catalogs. Locate your particular catalog there right click and choose delete. Note, your app may note work correctly after you delete a full text catalog.

Comment: I found that setting.  I'm going to test redirecting it and then deleting it to make sure it doesn't break something. Thank you

Comment: Unfortunately, redirecting it didn't work. It still was in use even with renaming the file. I'll do it off hours by deleting it in Live after a backup. Thanks

Comment: @RanG are you sure your application code doesn't need that FTS catalog anymore? Blindly deleting it may not be a good idea.

Comment: To be safe, I'm going to ask tech support if the app requires it.  I don't think so, but you're right, it's a good idea to make sure.  thanks.

Comment: Thank you @andrews. I removed it this evening. I took what you gave me and did the following. I first ran:    dbcc shrinkfile (ftrow_FTC,emptyfile) then I ran alter database to remove the file. The file is gone and the app continues to work. Thank you for your assistance.